# importing rules.csv file to sonar

Tags: sonarqube

i am having a file rules.csv  in ms-excel format. The rules.csv is downloaded from quality profiles of  other sonar server.Now i want to implement my sonar with same quality profiles.now my questions are

1. how to import csv file to sonar
2. rules.csv file is enough to create the same quality profiles of other

Comment: Did you create a backup of the sonar profile in the other server? On my machine this produces an xml file.

Comment: thanks oers for reply.i got it. i created backup profile which generated .xml file and in my machine i clicked restore profile and i gave xml that generated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Steps to make a backup/reimport

1. Go to **Configuration --> Quality Profiles**
2. Click the **Backup**-Button of the desired profile and save the file
3. Go to the target sonar instance
4. Go to **Configuration --> Quality Profiles**
5. Click **Restore Profile** (it is in the upper right corner and a bit hard to miss.)
6. Select the previously saved file
7. Done

Related Sonar documentation can be found [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Profile+Existence+Edits#ProfileExistenceEdits-Backingup/RestoringaProfile).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not admin on the source sonar and you want to get the profile there will be no backup button. Try to find out the internal ID of the profile (look at the link URL in the **Quality Profiles** list) and then download it like this:

```
curl http://target-sonar-instance/profiles/backup/15 -XPOST > ~/Downloads/profile.xml
```

(where `15` is the ID you found)