# How can I reuse the modified profile?

Tags: sonarqube

When I deployed a `sonarqube` on a server, I modified many rules and saved them as a new profile. Now I want to deploy a new `sonarqube`, is there a method I can copy the modified profile into this machine? Or I can only modify the rule one after another?

Comment: This is a duplicated question, and the answer can be found here:[importing rules.csv file to sonar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078061/importing-rules-csv-file-to-sonar).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the profile backup and restore feature.